# What am I missing in compiler options for linking with JSON-C static library?

Tags: c, static-libraries, json-c

I am trying to compile the `json-c-0.9` test binaries, while statically linking to `libjson.a`, which I have built and is sitting in `/path/to/json-c-0.9/lib`:

```
$ gcc -g -v -Wall -std=gnu99 -static -L/path/to/json-c-0.9/lib -ljson test1.c -o test1
```

I get numerous errors of the form:

```
/path/to/json-c-0.9/test1.c:17: undefined reference to `json_object_new_string'                                                        
/path/to/json-c-0.9/test1.c:18: undefined reference to `json_object_get_string'                                                        
/path/to/json-c-0.9/test1.c:19: undefined reference to `json_object_to_json_string'                                                    
/path/to/json-c-0.9/test1.c:20: undefined reference to `json_object_put'                                                               
/path/to/json-c-0.9/test1.c:22: undefined reference to `json_object_new_string'
etc.
```

What I am missing in trying to compile the test binaries? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With static linking, gcc only tries to bring in the symbols it needs based on what it has encountered already. In your case, you pass `-ljson` before your source files, so gcc brings in the static library and doesn't need anything from it, *then* tries to build your code.

Put the libraries to link against after your code.

```
$ gcc -g -v -Wall -std=gnu99 -static -L/path/to/json-c-0.9/lib test1.c -o test1 -ljson
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine Cmakelist.txt. untitled3,4 are the folder names. Remember to put header file in the same folder or direct to it correctly.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(untitled3 C )
#find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
ADD_LIBRARY(LibsModule
        main.c
        json.h
        libjson.c
        )

target_link_libraries(LibsModule -lpthread)
target_link_libraries(LibsModule libjson-c.a)
target_link_libraries(LibsModule libjson-c.4.dylib)

target_link_libraries(LibsModule -L/usr/local/Cellar/json-c/0.13.1/lib)

include_directories(/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig)
include_directories(untitled3)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(SOURCES  json.h main.c )

configure_file (
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/json.h"
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/json.h"
)


add_executable( untitled4 ${SOURCES} )

target_link_libraries(untitled4 LibsModule)
```